# Как вывести дублирующиеся цифры массива чтобы встречалось только 1 раз?

Tags: java, массивы, list

**Задача**: *Вывести дублирующиеся цифры.*

> Код:

```
int[] nums = new int[]{3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3}; 
// Значение которые повторяются, необходимо добавлять в List. List только для дубликатов.
```

> **Мой код:**

```
int[] nums = new int[]{3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3};
        List<Integer> list_3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if ((nums[i]) == nums[j]) {
                    list_3.add(nums[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Повторяющиеся цифры: " + list_3);
```

> Результат который выходит:

```
Повторяющиеся цифры: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3]
```

> Как должно быть?: *должно вывести такой результат:*

```
3,5
```

> **Вопрос:** Как через условие Contains сделать так чтобы число встречалось только один раз?

Comment: элементарно, в вашем коде вместо `if ((nums[i]) == nums[j])` используйте `if ((nums[i]) == nums[j]) && !list_3.contains(nums[i]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взять и сделать:

```java
int[] nums = new int[]{3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3};
List<Integer> list_3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if (nums[i] == nums[j] && !list_3.contains(nums[i])) {
            list_3.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Повторяющиеся цифры: " + list_3);
// -> [3, 5]
```

Другой вариант: вместо списка использовать сет, который по определению содержит только уникальные значения, тогда можно будет быстро пропускать уже обнаруженные дубликаты:

```java
int[] nums = new int[]{3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3};
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (set.contains(nums[i])) {
        continue;
    }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if (nums[i] == nums[j]) {
            set.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Повторяющиеся цифры: " + set);
// -> [3, 5]
```